# the orthogonal decomposition

Tags: geometry, riemannian-geometry

please I need help

Let $ B $ be a flat Euclidean abelian Lie algebra of dimension  $\mathrm{n} $ .
Suppose $\xi$ is nilpotent. There exists $\operatorname{} q \leq \operatorname{dim} B$  such that  $$ \{0\} \neq \operatorname{ker} \xi \varsubsetneqq \operatorname{ker} \xi^{2} \varsubsetneqq \cdots \varsubsetneqq \operatorname{ker} \xi^{q}=B $$ Then we have the orthogonal decomposition:  $$ B=\bigoplus_{k=0}^{q-1} F_{k} $$    where $ F_ {0} =\operatorname {ker} \xi $ and, for all  $k=1, \ldots, q-1, F_{k}=\operatorname{ker} \xi^{k+1} \cap\left(\operatorname{ker} \xi^{k}\right)^{\perp} .$

Question: Let us show that for all $ 1 \leq k \leq q-1 $: $$ \operatorname{dim}F_ {k} \leq \operatorname {dim} \operatorname{ker} \xi ^ {j}, j = 1, \ldots, k + 1 $$